# MySQL Comparasion of two databases and tables and get results

Tags: mysql, database, compare

I Have Two Databases (DTB1 and DTB2). I would like to show only results from DTB1 that is not equal in DTB2.I know which field i need to compare and that is Field MOUSES.

```
Example:
             DTB1         DTB2
CLICKS        0            1
MOUSES        1            1
HOUSES        2            1
CARS          3            1
```

Result the output result is CLICKS, HOUSES and CARS (because MOUSES have both equal values).

i try this...but my sql cpu is 94% when i try this query:

```
SELECT a.mouses FROM $database.$table a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.mouses FROM $database2.$table2 b WHERE b.mouses=a.mouses);
```

Any Help Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should run faster if you have an index on `$database2.$table2(mouses)`.

Comment: I have found soulution...above code is working perfectly only problem was that i have in my example one link adress that containts :/ and therefore function does not working because this function NOT EXISTS works only with strings and numbers not : and /.